# User management GPS tracking app

Tags: php, android, sql

I'd like to code an app where every people of a group can see each other on a map. I have a very basic code using PHP JSON and JAVA which upload my GPS coordinate on a database and I can retrieve them to show my position on a map.

I have two questions :

- I don't really know how to manage I only want to see the people in the group on my map. Should I give every people a unique ID a check if there are in or something like that ?
- Does someone has a sample of something that can work for me and I can adapt ?

Thx,

Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you want people belonging to a particular group should be able to see each other on map, so as pre your requirement I would suggest

1. Design a schema, where you can arrange people as per group, like giving each group a unique ID.
2. All the people should hold a reference to group he belong, perhaps foreign key to group table.

After this, It would be cake walk. You just need implement a service which would return you coordinates of all the member passing group ID. Thats it your job is done, now whenever you invoke you app for a user, query for other user belonging to same group and do your UI processing.

Hope it helps,
Techfist.

Comment: Thank you for replying ! I'm pretty new in the android world, do you have more specific explanations, I mean code stuff to help me ? I well understand your thought but I don't see how to really code this.

Comment: You should be having to pieces of code, one backend and other frontend, as you say you have coded in php your backend, i would suggest to first implement backend to support this functionality then you can proceed toward consuming data in frontend. I could only help with code if am able to see your rough design implementation of what you done so far.